# CASE types interval and time with time zone cannot be matched PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp, postgresql-11

I got an error `CASE types interval and time with time zone cannot be matched`
with a code below

How can I solve it?

date_end and date_start are timestamp(0). I need a difference between them or current_time in case when date_start is not null and date_end is null

```
select
       case when date_end is not null
              then date_end - date_start
       when date_start is not null
              then current_time
       else null
       end as diff,
       column2
       /*, another columns */

from t1
```

Comment: Your first WHEN condition an `interval` the second returns a `time` value. All expressions of a CASE must return the same data type and a `time` value is something different than an `interval`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name gave me an idea, so I just convert first interval to time with ::time, now it works

Comment: But is this what you actually need? I guess that the expression is to return the _duration_ of an event or a process, i.e. an interval. If so then change `then current_time` to `then current_time - date_start`, i.e. the event has started but not finished yet and this is the duration so far.